# ¿Porque me sale el error "else without if" en esta parte de mi codigo?

Tags: java

Si puse el import java.util.scanner pero esta mucho mas arriba en el codigo

```
                        float PE,CN,PG,CO,TT;
                        System.out.println("INGRESE LA CANTIDAD DE PRODUCTOS A COMPRAR");
                        CN=leer.nextFloat(); 

                        System.out.println("INGRESE EL COSTO DEL PRODUCTO");  
                        PE=leer.nextFloat();

                        TT=PE*CN;

                        System.out.println("EL TOTAL DEL PRODUCTO ES:" + TT);

                        System.out.println("INGRESE EL MONTO CON EL QUE SE PAGA");

                        PG=leer.nextFloat();

                        if (PG>=TT);

                        CO=PG-TT;

                        System.out.println("EL CAMBIO A DAR ES: " + CO);
```

Justo en este else me sale el error de "else without if"

```
                        else

                        System.out.println("NO SE PUEDE REALIZAR LA COMPRA: NO ALCANZA");
```

No  se si tenga algo que ver, pero estoy haciendo el codigo en Apache net beans

Comment: Buenas Jonathan como te ha comentado el compañero Isaac, existe ciertos errores semánticos en el código que una vez corregidos el programa funciona perfectamente, por otro lado me gustaría comentarte el uso de las variables en mayúsculas, es conocido el uso de las variables en mayúsculas cuando es una constante por lo que sería una buena practica el declararlas en minúsculas para que cuando una de ellas este en mayúsculas sepamos fácilmente que se trata de una constante. Un saludo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una sentencia `else` tiene que ir precedida de una sentencia `if` o `else if`. En tu caso, la sentencia `else` no lo cumple. Si quieres que las 2 instrucciones que están a continuación del `if` formen parte del bloque `if` **debes quitar el punto y coma al final de la sentencia `if` y usar llaves**. Quedaría así:

```
if (PG>=TT) {
  CO=PG-TT;
  System.out.println("EL CAMBIO A DAR ES: " + CO);
}
```

### ¿Por qué debes quitar el punto y coma de la instrucción `if`?

Una sentencia `if` (al igual que `else if`, `else`, `switch`, `for`, `while`) no lleva punto y coma al final. Si añades el punto y coma se considera que la instrucción siguiente es el punto y coma. Por tanto, se evalúa la condición y continúa en la siguiente instrucción, tanto si el resultado es `true` como si es `false`. De modo que nunca debes terminar una sentencia `if` con punto y coma.

### ¿Por qué debes añadir las llaves?

Si no usas llaves, solo la línea siguiente está dentro del bloque `if`. Por este motivo, para hacer el código más legible y evitar este tipo de problemas, se considera una buena práctica usar las llaves siempre, tanto si el bloque `if` consta de una sola instrucción como si son más.

Answer (score 0):

El error "**else without if**" aparece si:

**1** Pones la estructa condicional mal

```
if(){
   ...
} else {
   ...
} else if(){
   ...
}
```

Eso no se puede hacer ya que primero va el `if` luego opcionalmente `else if` y de ultimas va el `else`

**2** Cortas o añades palabras a los condicionales

```
    if();{
       ...
    } else {
       ...
    } elseif(){
       ...
    }
```

Aqui hay dos errores, el primero, es que hay un `;` donde no deveria estarlo, si pones `;` no puedes poner llaves, y al reves, y el segundo error, es que el `else if` debe ir separado